# passing a PHP variable to Ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am attempting to call a comments section through a modal, for this purpose I need to pass a unique id along with #display_comment . It works when I hard code is such as #display_comment1, #display_comment2. I need to know how to pass the value as a variable.

I am using dom-target to pass it as variable in myData1, but it wont work. The console shows #display_comment  & 1 on the next line.

```
<div id="dom-target" style="display: none;">
<?php       
  echo htmlspecialchars($test['id']);
?>
</div>
```

```
var div = document.getElementById("dom-target");
 var myData1 = div.textContent;
 load_comment();

 function load_comment()
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"fetch_comment.php",
   method:"POST",
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#display_comment'+myData1).html(data);
   }
  })
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @barmar wrote is correct. Although I would suggest a much better approach for this. Whenever you wanna "fetch" some html data to javascript (here the data is set by PHP), you can use the `data` attribute in html like this:

```html
<div id="dom-target" style="display: none;" data-id="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($test['id']);?>">
  <?php       
    echo htmlspecialchars($test['id']);
  ?>
</div>
```

See that I've set the `data` attribute to the `div` above with the id.

Now when you wanna get this id in jQuery, you can do it with `$("#dom-target").data("id");` like

```js
var myData1 = $("#dom-target").data("id");
```

This gives you a much better and cleaner way to fetch data from html to javascript.

Answer (score 3):

The DIV includes lots of whitespace around the ID. You need to remove that with `trim()`.

```
var myData1 = div.textContent.trim();
```